# problems with java.mail and sockets

Tags: java, sockets, email

I was trying to send a mail from java but I am getting the same error in every case I tried.
I'm using windows 8 and before i had problems with sockets,  but i run this code in a virtual machine with xp and it send me the same mistake! I read that it could be my jdk,firewall, antivirus or network problems but i already tried that and i have no solution. I hope someone could tell whats happening here! I'll leave the code here:

```
package mail;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Mail
{ // SE DECLARAN LAS VARIABLES DE CORREO , DOMINIO, PUERTO Y PASS

   private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.trust";
   private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 587;
   private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "josevalverde93@gmail.com";
   private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new Mail().test();
   }

   public void test() throws Exception {
      Properties props = new Properties();`
      props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");`
      props.put("mail.smtps.trust", SMTP_HOST_NAME);`
      props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");`
      props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");`
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "stmp.gmail.com");`
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");`
      props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "josevalverde93@gmail.com");`
      props.setProperty("mai.smtp.auth", "true");`
      Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);`
      mailSession.setDebug(true); Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();`
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession); `
      message.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");`

      // Aqui VA EL TITULO DEL EMAIL
      message.setContent("Este correo ha sido enviado desde Netbeans con Java", "text/plain");

      // Aqui VA EL CONTENIDO,,
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("andima9886@gmail.com"));

      // DESTINARIO
      transport.connect (SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);
      transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
      transport.close();
  }
```

}

The output is:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.trust", port 587, isSSL true
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to
host, port: smtp.gmail.trust, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.trust
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at mail.Mail.test(Mail.java:44)
    at mail.Mail.main(Mail.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.trust
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:176)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

Thank you, and greetings from Costa Rica.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't manually add `\`` everywhere.

Comment: Indeed it was done that way.

Comment: I hope the password you gave is not actual `password`

Comment: it was manually added and no, the password is not the actual password, do you have an idea?

Comment: If you are trying smtp.gmail.com, then what exception you are getting?

Comment: Better to "ping smtp.gmail.com" from CMD to check if you can reach there..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: i did the ping and i can reach it! but i still have no connection with the application in java :S

Comment: Thats probably because you set the property `mai.smtp.auth` when you mean `mail.smtp.auth`

Comment: thanks for that detail but i change it and still doesnt work :S

Comment: i run this application in Windows 7 with netbeans and it worked! Thanks to all the people that answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be "smtp.gmail.trust". Did you tried with "smtp.gmail.com"?

To send mail using Gmail SMTP, try below code, it works for me:

```
public void sendMail(final String senderEmailID, final String password, javax.mail.Address [] addresses) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmailID, password);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmailID));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);

        message.setSubject("Subject");

        String messageBody = "<h1>Message</h1>";

        message.setContent(messageBody.toString(), "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey hi, i run it on windows 7 and it works! But i have a doubt, in windows 8 the program returns that i dont have the certificate for validation! im using netbeans 7.3 and the last jdk! how could i certified it in my computer? @Meraman

Comment: Do you get certificate issue when you send mail from browser like Internet Explorer in Windows 8?

Comment: i dont use Internet Explorer i use firefox and i can send and receive mails normally! i dont know what happen :S i've already run it in several machines and only worked in one! :S

Comment: Ok, I think that is certificate issue with java. Can you post full stack trace when you get exception?

Comment: Check this: http://www.mathworks.in/support/solutions/en/data/1-FJ9AO8/?product=SL&solution=1-FJ9AO8

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at correografico.EnviarCorreo.jButton1ActionPerformed(EnviarCorreo.java:237)
 at correografico.EnviarCorreo.access$000(EnviarCorreo.java:25)
 at correografico.EnviarCorreo$1.actionPerformed(EnviarCorreo.java:64)...

Comment: this is the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

If you read the exception it says `UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.trust`. It can not find the host smtp.gmail.trust. You probably meant smtp.gmail.com.

Also, look though your code, you have several mistakes when setting your properties.

Comment: what exception you get when you try smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?